# getResource in Java based in the URI in Codenvy

Tags: java, codenvy

That's my controller:

```
public class GreetingController implements Controller
{

  private static final String MARKERS_FILE_NAME = "markers.txt";


   @Override
   public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
   {

        String result = null;

          File file = new File(getClass().getResource(MARKERS_FILE_NAME).toURI());
       }
}
```

I have the file markers.txt is in the same level of the controller but incomprehensibly I got a Nullpointer on this line: `File file = new File(getClass().getResource(MARKERS_FILE_NAME).toURI());`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.codenvy.example.spring.GreetingController.handleRequest(GreetingController.java:27)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
```

FYI: I am working with https://codenvy.com/

[image]

I also tried

```
  InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
               .getResourceAsStream("com/codenvy/example/spring/markers.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

With this result:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    com.codenvy.example.spring.GreetingController.handleRequest(GreetingController.java:32)
```

Comment: I think you are going to have specify the path to your file `markers.txt` _relative_ to the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the path to your file `markers.txt` *relative* to the root of the classpath.  Since your screen capture shows the package structure, this path is known.  Either of the following should work:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("com/codenvy/example/spring/SomeTextFile.txt");

InputStream in = this.getClass()
      .getResourceAsStream("/com/codenvy/example/spring/SomeTextFile.txt");
```

The snippets above return an `InputStream`, which hopefully is sufficient for you, assuming you are planning to read the files.